# jQuery slidetoggle multiple divs one at a time with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I'm trying to use `slideToggle()` on multiple div hover's, showing another div in its respected container div. Example:

```
<div class="container">123
   <div class="content">ABC</div>
</div>
<div class="container">123
   <div class="content">ABC</div>
</div>
```

It runs on a dynamic page so the number of containers could range from 1-25. I am trying to slideToggle the `"content"` class of each div on the container hover. I use this jQuery

```
function slide() {
   $(".content").slideToggle("fast");
   return false;
}

$(".container").hover(slide, slide);
```

It will only work on the first container/content div however. How can I make it slidetoggle each created div without 25 different jQuery functions? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So, are you trying to have every div.content slide simultaneously, or are you just trying to bind a common behavior to each div (where each div.content would slide independently when hovered over)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(".container").hover(function(){
$(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
});
```

Make sure you hide `.content` by default.

```
.content{
 display:none;
}
```

### check working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dWfU5/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to relate the container with the right content.

```
function slide() {
   $(this).find(".content").slideToggle("fast");
   return false;
}

$(".container").hover(slide, slide);
```

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/BywXh/).

P.S. why are you returning false in slide ?

Comment: @return false. its good practice for most other events, and old habbits die hard....

Answer (score 0):

Heres another possiblity: http://jsfiddle.net/UfjMe/5/

Works by looping through each item, hiding, then adding the hover command.